# Correcty align text with image in constraintlayout in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-constraintlayout, android-jetpack-compose

this is my code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ShowSplashHeader() {
    ConstraintLayout() {
        val (logo, text1, text2) = createRefs()
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.logo),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(logo) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top, margin = 32.dp)
                start.linkTo(parent.start, margin = 16.dp)
            }
            .size(45.dp)
        )
        Text(
            "First line text",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            color = colorResource(R.color.green_light),
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(text1) {
                top.linkTo(logo.top, margin = 0.dp)
                start.linkTo(logo.end, margin = 4.dp)
            }
        )
        Text(
            "Second line text",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            color = colorResource(R.color.green_light),
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(text2) {
                start.linkTo(text1.start)
                bottom.linkTo(logo.bottom, margin = 0.dp)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

I am getting this:

[image]

I need to set the first line with the top alignment with the image and the second line with the bottom alignment. It is obvious that constraints are correctly set and that the `Text` should not have inner padding but I don't know how to fix it.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It happens because text has inner padding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack Compose, centering text without font padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66126551/jetpack-compose-centering-text-without-font-padding)

Comment: As @Philip suggested, https://stackoverflow.com/a/68612775/6021469
this solution works