# Remove font padding in Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm having problems with Japanese font types. Specifically with the font Noto Sans JP. When I apply the font to `Text`, I see that the vertical padding of the font seems too wide.

[image: Example]

Here is my text display code:

```
Text(
    text = "地域のお得は\nすべてここに",
    style = Typography.h4,
)

// Typography
val Typography = Typography(
    ...
    h4 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = NotoSans,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 34.sp,
        letterSpacing = 0.25.sp
    ),
    ...
)

// Import font
private val NotoSans = FontFamily(
    Font(R.font.noto_sans_black, FontWeight.Black),
    Font(R.font.noto_sans_light, FontWeight.Light),
    Font(R.font.noto_sans_bold, FontWeight.Bold),
    Font(R.font.noto_sans_thin, FontWeight.Thin),
    Font(R.font.noto_sans_medium, FontWeight.Medium),
    Font(R.font.noto_sans_regular, FontWeight.Normal),
)
```

Link font: [Noto Sans JP](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+JP)

I want to remove vertical padding of Text. With Android Baseview, there is `includeFontPadding = false` attribute to remove font padding. But with Android Compose I can't find any properties with similar functionality.

So in Android Compose, is there a way to remove the vertical padding of the font?

Comment: Did you try line spacing extra?

Comment: @AslamHossin Did you mean `lineHeight`? It doesn't work because it resets the spacing between lines, not the padding in the text box.

Comment: Then another way to remove the extra padding, you can try contentInsetStart with 0dp. It worked for me in native development though I didn’t try it in compose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack Compose, centering text without font padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66126551/jetpack-compose-centering-text-without-font-padding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my question. By using `Compose 1.2.0-alpha07` and above, you can use `PlatformTextStyle` api to set `includeFontPadding`.

Try to the below code:

```
private val NotoSans = FontFamily(
    Font(R.font.noto_san_jp_black, FontWeight.Black),
    Font(R.font.noto_san_jp_light, FontWeight.Light),
    Font(R.font.noto_san_jp_bold, FontWeight.Bold),
    Font(R.font.noto_san_jp_thin, FontWeight.Thin),
    Font(R.font.noto_san_jp_medium, FontWeight.Medium),
    Font(R.font.noto_san_jp_regular, FontWeight.Normal),
)

val Typography = Typography(
    headlineLarge = Typography().headlineLarge.copy(
        fontFamily = NotoSans,
    )
)

@OptIn(ExperimentalTextApi::class)
/* ... */

Text(
    text = "地域のお得は\nすべてここに",
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge.copy(
        platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
            includeFontPadding = false
        )
    /* ... */
    )
)
```

**The result when `includeFontPadding = false`:**

[image: includeFontPadding = false]

**The result when `includeFontPadding = true` or no using it:**

[image: includeFontPadding = true or not using]

**More information:**

[Fixing Font Padding in Compose Text - Medium](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/fixing-font-padding-in-compose-text-768cd232425b)

Answer (score -1):

The Japanese font Noto Sans JP does show an unusual amount of extra white-space or gap above the first line of text when displayed on a screen:

[image: NotoSans-font-with-gap]

However, this gap can be reduced by including a negative padding offset in the Text() composable - see 'modifier' parameter below:

```
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    Text(
        text = "地域のお得は\nすべてここに",
        fontFamily = NotoSans,
        style = Typography.h4,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 0.dp).offset(y = (-30).dp)
    )
}
```

This results in the same text being displayed, but without the gap:

[image: NotoSans-font-without-gap]

If you would like to adjust the line spacing between the lines then you can add the "lineHeight" parameter to either the TextStyle() composable in the 'Type.kt' file **or** the Text() composable in the 'MainActivity.kt' file, as required; e.g. in this instance "lineHeight = 80.sp":

[image: NotoSans-font-with-line-spacing]

Hope this is helpful to someone!