# Compose Text is not showing as center inside the Box when outer parent is being used fixed size

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, android-jetpack-compose-ui

Below is my Compose UI Code.

```
Card(Modifier.height(150.dp)
                    .weight(1.0F)) {
                Box (modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center){
                    Text(text = "A", fontSize = 130.sp)
                }

            }
```

Below is how UI look, Consider this code for the Compose Multiplaform not only to the android

[image]

We can see that the letter A is not centered inside the Card view.

Comment: Try to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66126551/jetpack-compose-centering-text-without-font-padding)

Comment: Thanks, Till date i am not aware of this, will try and let u know

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bylazy

I change my code and it's working now.

```
Card(Modifier.height(150.dp)
                    .weight(1.0F)) {

                Box (modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center){
                    Text(text = "A", fontSize = 130.sp,style = TextStyle(
                        platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
                            includeFontPadding = false
                        )
                    ))
                }

            }
```